# Reading XAML via string in Code behind Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, app-config, resourcedictionary

I am trying to create xamarin PCL project with multiple resource dictionary 's in the sane project.

All the resource dictionary 's  have the same key defined (these keys are being referenced as Dynamic Resources) in project XAML files for different screens, but the values in each resource dictionary 's  is different(Purpose is having a separate resource dictionary 's  for specific client requirements).

Am able to load the resource dictionary 's  in Code behind of App.Xaml using

Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
Resources.MergedWith = typeof(Sales); // Sales.xaml is a resource dictionary.

Now am trying to pass the Name of the resource dictionary from App.config (using PCLAppConfig Nuget package) and get the name of the XAML file along with its path.

Am unable to read the XAML file in Code Behind just like we use to do in WPF by using XAMLReader.Load

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ResourceDictionary will have its own type, e.g. Sales.

Hence if you want to get the type dependant upon a name, you could just get the type via reflection.

```
var nameFromConfig = "Sale"; // Change to get from your config file
var type = Type.GetType(nameFromConfig);
Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary(); 
Resources.MergedWith =  type;
```

Comment: the type using 
Type.GetType(nameFromConfig) always comes as null.
I have tried using the name in config file with .xaml and without as well. The path to file is also set to correct.

Comment: You will need to use the full namespace to that type.

Comment: I am still unable to get the type name using the full namespace.
Here is the code :-

var fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testkey"];
            string file = @"C:\Users\piyush.poddar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App3\App3\App3\App3." + fileName;
            var type = Type.GetType(file);
            Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary();
            Resources.MergedWith = type;

App.config entry is as follows:-
<appSettings>
  <add key="testkey" value="sales.xaml" />
 </appSettings>

Comment: For each XAML file, you should have code behind as well, with an InitializeComponent, To get the type you need the full namespace of this codebehind class, not the file path.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I am now able to achieve this using Full namespace.